# How to use next.js 14 zustand in client component

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-context, zustand

I would like to fetch data in my layout.tsx and then share across my entire app. In order to achieve that I am fetching the data in layout and pass it into the Provider.

layout.tsx

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://65ca740b3b05d29307e05057.mockapi.io/productsserver",
    {
      cache: "no-cache",
      next: {
        tags: ["products"],
      },
    }
  );

  const products: Product[] = await res.json();

  return (
    <html lang="en">
        <ProductStoreProvider products={products}>
          <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
        </ProductStoreProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

ProductProvider.tsx

```
"use client";
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { Product } from "@/actions/actions";

interface ProductState {
  products: Product[];
}

const createStore = (products: ProductState) => ({
  products,
});

const ProductContext = createContext<ReturnType<typeof createStore> | null>(
  null
);

const ProductStoreProvider = ({
  products,
  children,
}: {
  products: ProductState;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const [store] = useState(() => createStore(products));

  console.log("Product Provider", store);
  //  { product: 'Shirt', price: '798.00', id: '9' },
  //  { product: 'Fish', price: '114.00', id: '10' },
  //  { product: 'Pants', price: '645.00', id: '11' },
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={store}>{children}</ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useProductStore = () => {
  if (!ProductContext)
    throw new Error(
      "useProductStore must be used within a ProductStoreProvider"
    );
  return useContext(ProductContext)!;
};

export default ProductStoreProvider;
```

I added a sanity check console.log() in there which gives me the output I expect.

In the page.tsx which is a server component I fetch the data again - because that's apparently how to do this.

```
export default async function Home() {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://65ca740b3b05d29307e05057.mockapi.io/productsserver",
    {
      cache: "no-cache",
      next: {
        tags: ["products"],
      },
    }
  );

  const products: Product[] = await res.json();

  return (
    <main className="">
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center">Server Products</h1>
           <h2 className="font-bold p-5">List of Products</h2>
      <div className="flex gap-5 flex-wrap">
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
            <p>{product.product}</p>
            <p>{product.price}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <ClientOverview />

    </main>
  );
}
```

The problem is the client component:

```
"use client";

import { useProductStore } from "@/store/ProductStore";

function ClientOverview() {
  const { products } = useProductStore();

  console.log(products);  // Empty Array []

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-5 flex-wrap">
      <h1>Client Producuts</h1>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
          <p>{product.product}</p>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClientOverview;
```

even though inside the provider it tells me that it fetched the data its not coming back from the store. How do I pass fresh data down to the client component?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of issues.

Perhaps if the client component(ClientOverview()) is loading first before the state is loaded, data could be empty in the state.

This could be the reason why  `const { products } = useProductStore()` is returning empty array.

Can you implement this:

```
{products.length !=0 ?( <div className="flex gap-5 flex-wrap">
      <h1>Client Producuts</h1>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
          <p>{product.product}</p>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>)
:
(
// else load a temporary div to for faster error debugging
<div>state not available</div>
)
}
```

Now that you have  a indicator to see if the state has been loaded:-

Try to figure out, if the state is loaded initially before the clientoverview() works.

Instead of fetching the api, set up the state manually to see if the clientcomponent is rendering!!

Comment: yeah the product is undefined at this point. I also just noticed that following this article https://medium.com/lets-make-something-up/creating-light-dark-mode-on-a-react-app-with-context-589a5465f639 that in there case "darkmode" is undefined. Only when you toggle it becomes defined.

Comment: Can you only implement a if statement to only fetch from the store if the array.length is not equal to 0

``````

Comment: I could do that but that wouldn't change anything. What I would need is a way is const { products } = useProductStore() to run again when the store is updated but for that I would need to have access to the store in the first place.

Comment: You can use useEffect() and use products as variable inside the array dependency.
So that when the dependency (products) gets loaded in, would cause the rerender of all the useEffect used pages.

 Let me know if that works using zustand. I always prefer to work the original state management tool(Redux) since the community is huge behind it...

Comment: ```function ClientOverview() {
  const { products } = useProductStore();
  //console.log(products); // Empty Array []
 
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(products);
  }, [products]);

}```  this never gets triggered and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that will either get me a new job or shot but I hope it works for someone in dire need.

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <TanStackProvider>{children}</TanStackProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

wrap the app in Tanstackquery if you want to get the data in the server component then do this:

```
export default async function Home() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: getData,
  });

  const products = dehydrate(queryClient).queries[0].state.data;

  return (
    <HydrationBoundary state={dehydrate(queryClient)}>
        <h2 className="font-bold p-5">List of Products</h2>
        <div className="flex gap-5 flex-wrap">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
              <p>{product.product}</p>
              <p>{product.price}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <ClientOverview />
    </HydrationBoundary>
  );
}
```

so prefetch the query on the server then dehydrate it on the server to access the data for server rendering and pass it on to the client where it can be used

```
function ClientOverview() {
  //const { products } = useProductStore();

  //console.log(products); // Empty Array []
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["products"],
    queryFn: getData,
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-5 flex-wrap">
      <h1>Client Producuts</h1>
      {data?.map((product) => (
        <div key={product.id} className="p-5 shadow">
          <p>{product.product}</p>
          <p>{product.price}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClientOverview;
```

I would have really prefered to use zustand and the provider stuff but can't get it to work.